# Fault tolerance of MBQC

Tags: error-correction, fault-tolerance, measurement-based-qc

Is there a proof that measurement-based quantum computation can be fault tolerant under any noise model? Or at least, under any noise model with small enough correlation length?

Comment: Is there a reason why the RHG paper doesn't meet this requirement? https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0510135

Comment: Yes- they consider relatively simple noise model, with only single-qubit, spacial and temporal independent errors (which can propagate to only a limited distance due to the preparation process). This is not the case in some realistic applications.

Comment: For what it's worth, the RHG cluster state can correct arbitrary local errors, including loss. The errors don't have to be depolarizing or single-qubit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Fault-tolerant quantum computation with cluster states"<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.71.042323)</sup>, Nielsen and Dawson (2005) studied fault-tolerance in MBQC with cluster states. They proved threshold theorems similar to the well-known threshold theorem for quantum circuit model.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about a further work that generalize their work to include both leakage/loss and non-Markovian noise, or that uses weaker noise locality assumptions?